# Retrieve the Value from Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following sctructure JSON data.

Json Data:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "downloadUrl" : "XXXX",
    "path" : "XXXX",
    "id" : "XXXX",
    "repository" : "XXXX",
    "format" : "XXXX",
  }, {
    "downloadUrl" : "XXXX",
    "path" : "XXXX",
    "id" : "XXXX",
    "repository" : "XXXX",
    "format" : "XXXX",
  }, {
    "downloadUrl" : "XXXX",
    "path" : "XXXX",,
    "id" : "XXXX",
    "repository" : "XXXX",
    "format" : "XXXX",
  } ],
  "continuationToken" : "YYYY"
}
```

I need to get the item value in List (`List<repository>`). How can I retrieve the Values?

**downloadUrl,path,id,repository,format,continuoationToken**

I have try to get below like this.

```
class Program
    {
        public class repository
        {
            public NpmPackages items { get; set; }
        }
        public class NpmPackages
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "downloadUrl")]
            public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "path")]
            public string Path { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "repository")]
            public string Repository { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "format")]
            public string Format { get; set; }
        }
        public static string HttpOperation(string apiUrl)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiUrl) == true)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(apiUrl));
            }

            Uri url = new Uri(apiUrl);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<repository> packageDetails = new List<repository>();
            List<repository> packageData = new List<repository>();
            var jsonData = HttpOperation("XXXX");
            packageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<repository>>(jsonData);
            packageDetails.AddRange(packageData);

        }
    }
```

While try like this I am facing below error.

Error Details:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[npm_clean_up_Tool.Program+NpmPackages]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'items', line 2, position 11.

please update your suggestions to achieve my goal.

Comment: Your declaration is faulted. Follow the steps in the duplicate to get valid classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NpmPackages>(jsonstring.ToString());
```